# Unexpeced token error when setting contentType to application/json

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, post, content-type

I am sending data using AJAX POST. The data is JSON format. See below. However, I keep getting **'Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0'**. Why is this happening? The reason I am setting contentType here is so that the Boolean field `checked` does not get converted to string.

```
var data = {
  "user": "tom",
  "number": 9,
  "checked": false
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
    success: function (success) {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: where do you get the error? When the javascript runs or when you recieve the answer?

Comment: @LioraHaydont previously I did not have `contentType: 'application/json' ` and the backend is treating the Boolean like a  string, so I read that I should set it to avoid this issue. Which I did, and now it won't even get sent to the backend server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `contentType: 'application/json',` you need to stringify the data yourself:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

As for the error that seems like a response problem. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see what is actually contained in the reponse body

Comment: The quoted error would be happening server side (and perhaps then included in the response), because the server is receiving the data as `user=tom&number=9&checked=false` so the first character in the request body is the "u" from "user" and obviously that can't be parsed as JSON.